# Watch file source code

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, file-format

How  can I see all files formats that supported by `file` binary?

For example `file my_bin`

Comment: Any OS treats any file as an array of bytes. (Exception: Kernel knows about ELF (executable program and object files) and Shebang (executable shell scripts.) Almost every "binary" file format is related to the specific program suite that "owns" the format (tar, Oracle, PDF, Mathematica, zip, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ian Darwin’s version of `file`](https://www.darwinsys.com/file/), the most common nowadays, supports an `-l`  option which will list the names of the supported patterns; for example

```
$ file -l
Set 0:
Binary patterns:
Strength = 190@5: (WP) loadable text []
Strength =  60@8: (Corel/WP) []
Text patterns:
Set 1:
Binary patterns:
Text patterns:
Set 0:
Binary patterns:
Strength = 190@5: (WP) loadable text []
Strength =  60@8: (Corel/WP) []
Strength = 500@47: Biosig/Brainvision Marker file [biosig/brainvision]
Strength = 490@122: Biosig/TMSiLOG [biosig/tmsilog]
Strength = 461@127: Biosig/SYNERGY [biosig/synergy]
...
```

`file` supports a huge number of different patterns; the above command produces nearly 3,000 on the systems I’ve run it on.

If you want to explore the source code, it is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/file/file).

Comment: I looking all file supported under `ubuntu`. How can I find that please?

Comment: What do you mean? `file -l` works on 16.04 and 20.04

Comment: @File  Ubuntu does not "support" the file types as listed, in any real sense. The distro merely provides a tool that interprets a few bytes in many file types so it can identify things like: "AVG 7 Antivirus vault file data". Interpreting the actual data (possibly a proprietary format) is strictly in the domain of the appropriate application. You might download that (free or paid), or the app may only run on another OS.